# Need help downloading steam on ubuntu!

Tags: crash

I'm having trouble downloading steam to Ubuntu, his is my first time trying this I have a Google Chromebook and i tried to YouTube how to download steam and i pretty much have it, but it says that i'm missing some files steam needs in order to download. I've tried everything i don't know what to do or what i'm doing honestly. I need some help

Comment: You mention that you're on a Google Chromebook. Just to be clear, ChromeOS and Ubuntu are not the same thing.

I know that might be obvious to some, I just want to make sure that's not the root of your issue.

Comment: Paste the output of the error, what packages are missing? I hope you already tried to do `sudo apt-get install steam`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and try with the following things,

```
pushd /tmp

sudo apt-get install -y curl wget && \

wget -E http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb && \

sudo dpkg -i steam.deb ; \

sudo apt-get install -yf && \
```

After installing please use exit command,

```
exit
```

Hope the above helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please just go to the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/) and [install steam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher/) that way.  It is painless and I've never seen it fail.  I suspect it may require you to uninstall what you've already installed, but hopefully you can do that from the software center as well,